# Чтение данных из файла в java

Tags: java

Если в фале в одной строке даны и символы и числа, как правильно считывать данные чтобы была возможность сохранить и int и char отдельно.
Например если в файле написано A55-B22, как можно сделать int55 и 22 char А и В??

Comment: Данные у вас только такого формата?

Comment: да, примерно такого. Решаю задачу про шахматы и интересно как такие данные лучше считывать.

Comment: Может быть, использовать JSON или XML? Оно, конечно, займёт больше места, чем бинарный формат, но зато глазами всё видно, что удобно при отладке. Или есть задача минимизировать объём?

Comment: Если же Вы уже располагаете строкой, про которую известно, что там есть одна буква, потом одна-две цифры, потом разделитель, потом опять буква и цифры - то это проще всего распарсить регулярным выражением.

Comment: Используйте [java.util.scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) и его методы nextInt и next().charAt(0)

Comment: Scanner можно было бы использовать, если бы была точно известна последовательность символов и  цифр и она не менялась.

Comment: А про XML и JSON я еще ничего пока не знаю, java не так давно начал изучать, попробую разобраться Спасибо.  А про распарсить регулярным выражением не совсем понял, можете немного подробнее рассказать...

Comment: А можете рассказать что это за шахматы у которых есть поле под номером 55!?